# Can a repunit number be a perfect number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

Can a repunit number be a perfect number?

I think a repunit number can be a perfect number, since the last digit of an odd perfect number can be $1$.

Am I correct?

Comment: More generally, Pollack, [Perfect numbers with identical digits](http://pollack.uga.edu/repdigits.pdf)  $(2011)$ shows the only repdigit perfect number is $6$, and there are only finitely many repdigit perfect numbers in base $g$, and they are effectively computable.

Comment: The answer is yes, if you choose the right base. $11$ base $5$ works, uh, perfectly.

Comment: I honestly do not understand the three pending votes to close this question.  Considering that [Smart231](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1156728) is a low-reputation MSE user, and that *appropriate context* was indeed provided for the inquiry, can we just be a little bit more lenient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **NO**, a repunit number cannot be a perfect number.  (**Edit:** The following assumes base-$10$.  If base-$5$ is considered, then as pointed out in [a comment by Oscar Lanzi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678542/can-a-repunit-number-be-a-perfect-number/4678636#comment9892225_4678542), ${11}_{5} = {6}_{10}$ is perfect and a repdigit.)

---

To see why, consider an odd perfect number $N$, assuming such a number exists.

Euler showed that $N$ must have the so-called *Eulerian form*
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Since $N > {10}^{1500}$ as shown by [Ochem and Rao (2012)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4.pdf), then in particular $N$ cannot be equal to $1$.  This means that, under the assumption that $N$ is a repunit number, then $N$ has the form
$$N = 100\overline{N} + 11$$
whence
$$N \equiv 3 \pmod 4$$
holds.  This contradicts the *Eulerian form*, since $N$ must be congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to PSQs (& dupes), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Care to link to the question that is an exact duplicate of this one, @BillDubuque?

Comment: Did someone claim it was an "exact duplicate"?

Comment: I do not think that the question is a PSQ, as the OP provided context.  Hence, your [comment here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678542/can-a-repunit-number-be-a-perfect-number/4678636?noredirect=1#comment9892189_4678636) implies that the question is an "exact duplicate".  Please let me know if my understanding is correct, @BillDubuque.

Comment: It has 3 votes to close as PSQ. Your logic is puzzling.